# Use RangeSeekBar to play a section of the audio between the two thumbs

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rangeseekbar

So, what I am trying to do is to play a portion or section of the audio between the two thumbs- min and max of the rangeSeekBar. I have used the below library to achieve this feature. 
https://github.com/YahooArchive/android-range-seek-bar

With some logic from my side, I have achieved the functionality. But I don't know the audio doesn't always stop at the max position. Also, now since I am using custom view, I can't show a progress indicator like where is the currect audio been played. RangeSeekbar doesn't have the below method.

> seekbar.setProgress(int duration);

So, its very difficult to see where the music is actually playing. I want a feature something like this.

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Below are the related code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RangeSeekBar<Integer> mRangeSeekBar;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
Button playButton;
TextView mEndTextView;
static int max;
SeekBar mSeekBar;

Runnable mRunnable;
Handler mHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRangeSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.rangeSeekBar);
    mSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    mRangeSeekBar.setNotifyWhileDragging(true);
    playButton = findViewById(R.id.play);
    mEndTextView = findViewById(R.id.end_duration);
    mHandler = new Handler();

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    max = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();

  mRangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(0, mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
    mSeekBar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            playProgress();
        }
    });

    mRangeSeekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(minValue);
             max = maxValue;

        }
    });
}

private void playProgress() {
        if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() == max) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playProgress();
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 0);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/rangeSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

**Dependency**

> implementation 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'

Comment: Have you found any solution?